# How to understand the word "if" in case it means neither condition nor assumption?

Tags: word-meaning, conditional-constructions

I saw this sentence in *Reader's Choice* (P296):

> **If** this book begins with a familiar theme - the Native American experience of the last 120 years - the author brings to it great power and deep understanding.

The answer to the comprehension of this sentence is as following:

- The book begins with a familiar theme.
- The author of this sentence likes the book.

Given the answer, I am confused because the (bolded) word *if* here doesn't mean a condition, nor does it mean an assumption. So what exactly is going on?

Answer (score 1):

This is the *if* that the [OED describes in sense 4](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/91152), the one that means

> Even if, even though; though; granted that.

It calls this one a “pregnant” sense.

One citation provided for this sense of *if* is:

> - **1969**   *Listener* 24 Apr. 585/1 —   If Mozart was a life-long admirer of J. C. Bach, his views on Clementi were disparaging, to put it mildly.

Answer (score 1):

> If this book begins with a familiar theme—the Native American experience of the last 120 years—the author brings to it great power and deep understanding.

This is a complicated conditional. The reviewer has omitted the actual consequence clause, his recommendation of the book, because it is inferrable from the comment on it which occupies its place—something like:

> ... *it is nonetheless well worth reading, because* the author brings to it great power...

Such a 'covert' consequence (the term is Declerck and Reed's) is quite common. However, the sentence is further complicated by the reviewer's discreet (if not downright mealy-mouthed) reluctance to explicitly label the theme as one which has been so widely treated that readers are likely to dismiss the book—"Oh, just another book on the Native American experience". The reviewer encodes this likely response in the word *familiar*. So what the sentence really means is something like:

> Even though this book treats a familiar and overworked theme, the Native American experience, it is nonetheless well worth reading, because the author brings to it an unusual power and understanding.